# There is no quality in this world that is not what it is merely by contrast.

Tags: negation, free-relative-clauses, existentials, parsing

https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/h/hermanmelv108817.html

> There is no quality in this world that is not what it is merely by contrast. Nothing exists in itself.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 3):

Bracket out the "information packaging":

> <s>There is</s> no quality in this world <s>that</s> is not what it is merely by contrast. Nothing exists in itself.
>      ⇓
>   No quality in this world is not what it is merely by contrast. Nothing exists in itself.

Now "cancel out" the two negatives:

> [No] quality in this world is [not] what it is merely by contrast. Nothing exists in itself.
>      ⇓
>   Every quality in this world is what it is merely by contrast. Nothing exists in itself.

To paraphrase:

> Every quality is defined, not in itself, but by contrast with other qualities.

Or, as it was put by Ferdinand de Saussure, the founder of modern linguistics:

> A language is a system of differences with no positive terms.

A concrete example is provided if you locate Melville’s aphorism in its original context:

> We felt very nice and snug, the more so since it was so chilly out of doors; indeed out of bed-clothes too, seeing that there was no fire in the room. The more so, I say, because truly to enjoy bodily warmth, some small part of you must be cold, for there is no quality in this world that is not what it is merely by contrast. Nothing exists in itself. If you flatter yourself that you are all over comfortable, and have been so a long time, then you cannot be said to be comfortable any more. But if, like Queequeg and me in the bed, the tip of your nose or the crown of your head be slightly chilled, why then, indeed, in the general consciousness you feel most delightfully and unmistakably warm. For this reason a sleeping apartment should never be furnished with a fire, which is one of the luxurious discomforts of the rich. For the height of this sort of deliciousness is to have nothing but the blanket between you and your snugness and the cold of the outer air. Then there you lie like the one warm spark in the heart of an arctic crystal.

Comment: @user8153 No, just the opposite: the definition derives from the contrast. There is no such thing as *hot* unless you have a corresponding *cold*, there is no such thing as *rich* unless you have a corresponding *poor*.

Comment: @user8153 Just the opposite. Merely here = [**only, entirely, by itself, nothing other than**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/merely?showCookiePolicy=true). A quality is defined entirely by contrast, only by contrast, by contrast by itself, by nothing other than contrast.

Comment: @user8153 Bring this to chat, [**here**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15433/nothing-exists-in-itself)